# ng-bootstrap popover inside <a> tag

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, popover, ng-bootstrap

My question is very simple, have a Angular 5 component to have a question link as follows:

```
<a href="">¿Do you have any problem?</a>
```

I want to add a popover over  element (in the top position), so that when you click on it, show the popover and when you click again the popover will hide.

like that:

[ng-bootstrap example](http://%20https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)

but instead of a button it's a link.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same way under a tag like below

```
<a class="your-class" placement="top" ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
  Popover on top
</a>
```

Working demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jewqs1

Answer (score 0):

You can have this below code

```
<a class="icon-info" [ngbTooltip]="HelpContent" #toolTip="ngbTooltip" (click)="toolTip.open()"></a>

<ng-template #HelpContent>
  Here is Help content
</ng-template>
```